# Alternative section title using multicol

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, multicol

Compiling the following documents throws an error: "! Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete." I just want to add an alternative name to the table of contents and have no idea why this should be a problem using multicol :-)

```
\documentclass[%
paper=B5,%
]{scrbook}%
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section[test]{Test}]

Test

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to use a `{}` pair around the `[]` of `\section` macro, i.e. `\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{[test]}{Test}]`, since LaTeX's `\@ifnextchar` macro is confused about the wrapped `[` and it ends prematurely

Comment: aha, that works (actually putting braces around the complete \section[]{}, too). But why? :-)

Comment: It is actually explained in the linked question/answer

Comment: aha, somehow it wasn't displayed some seconds ago. thank you so much :-)

Comment: Actually I meant the first `]` is the cause of premature ending